# Parsing a soap response to json in php

Tags: php, json, xml, web-services, soap

I have the following soap which is a response from an API that I am consuming. I am trying to parse SOAP response to JSON.

So far I have this soap that I have put into a variable `$xml`

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                <SOAP-ENV:Body>
                    <ns0:stkCallback xmlns:ns0="safaricom.co.ke/Schemas/STK/CallbackExternal">
                        <ns0:MerchantRequestID>6h0rrD9ndK</ns0:MerchantRequestID>
                        <ns0:CheckoutRequestID>ws_CO_24082017105721840</ns0:CheckoutRequestID>
                        <ns0:ResultCode>0</ns0:ResultCode>
                        <ns0:ResultDesc>The service request has been accepted successfully.</ns0:ResultDesc>
                        <ns0:CallbackMetadata>
                            <ns0:Item>
                                <ns0:Name>Amount</ns0:Name>
                                <ns0:Value>1000.00</ns0:Value>
                            </ns0:Item>
                            <ns0:Item>
                                <ns0:Name>MpesaReceiptNumber</ns0:Name>
                                <ns0:Value>LHO31AMTRJ</ns0:Value>
                            </ns0:Item>
                            <ns0:Item>
                                <ns0:Name>Balance</ns0:Name>
                                <ns0:Value/>
                            </ns0:Item>
                            <ns0:Item>
                                <ns0:Name>TransactionDate</ns0:Name>
                                <ns0:Value>20170824105143</ns0:Value>
                            </ns0:Item>
                            <ns0:Item>
                                <ns0:Name>PhoneNumber</ns0:Name>
                                <ns0:Value>254713167623</ns0:Value>
                            </ns0:Item>
                        </ns0:CallbackMetadata>
                    </ns0:stkCallback>
                </SOAP-ENV:Body>
            </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>';
```

I need to create JSON response from the data which can be found between `<SOAP-ENV:Body>` tags. How can I do this?

Comment: Have a look at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13245008/how-to-get-json-response-from-soap-call-in-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13245008/how-to-get-json-response-from-soap-call-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this ?

```
// a bit of a hack, but let's see...
list($trash,$xml)=explode('<soap:Body>',$xml);
list($xml,$trash)=explode('</soap:Body>',$xml);
unset($xml);
$result=str_replace('xmlns="url"','',$xml);

$simple_result=simplexml_load_string($xml);
$json_result=json_encode($simple_result);

//var_export($simple_result);
echo $json_result;
```